# How can I modify my SQL to speed it up?

Tags: php, mysql

The old sql is like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tp_count 
FROM sdb_b2c_orders 
WHERE pay_status='1' 
    and createtime>1413533130 
    and area_code in (1030,1031,1032,1033) 
    and member_id in (
        select member_id 
            from sdb_invite_invite 
            where in_member_id=14273 
                or in_member_id=13742 
                or in_member_id=14299
    ) 
LIMIT 1;
```

It is result is `22`

But it is slow and I want to modify it to make it faster.  The new sql is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tp_count 
    FROM sdb_b2c_orders AS bo 
        INNER JOIN sdb_invite_invite AS ii ON bo.member_id=ii.in_member_id 
    WHERE bo.pay_status='1' 
        AND bo.area_code IN (1030,1031,1032,1033) 
        AND bo.createtime>1413533130 
        AND ii.in_member_id IN (14273,13742,14299)
```

But it is result is `131`...why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `exists` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tp_count
FROM sdb_b2c_orders o
WHERE pay_status = '1' and createtime > 1413533130 and area_code in (1030,1031,1032,1033) and
      exists (select 1
              from sdb_invite_invite i
              where i.member_id = o.member_id and i.in_member_id in (14273, 13742, 14299) 
             );
```

You can also improve performance with indexes.  I would recommend `sdb_b2c_orders(pay_status, createtime, area_code, member_id)` and `sdb_invite_invite(member_id, in_member_id)`.

Comment: Thanks!Yours help is right. But how can i use `join` to do it ?

Comment: If this improves performance, why do you *need* to use an explicit `join`?

Comment: `join`(200ms) is faster than `exists`(1600ms)——ps:`in where`(2000ms)

Comment: @walter . . . Is that with the indexes that I describe.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS tp_count 
>       FROM sdb_b2c_orders AS bo 
>           INNER JOIN sdb_invite_invite AS ii ON bo.member_id=ii.in_member_id 
>       WHERE bo.pay_status='1' 
>           AND bo.area_code IN (1030,1031,1032,1033) 
>           AND bo.createtime>1413533130 
>           AND ii.in_member_id IN (14273,13742,14299)

fixed `bo.memeber_id=ii.in_member_id` to `bo.member_id=ii.member_id`

Then it works!